# How to only allow classes that require a specific type of generic

Tags: typescript, class, typescript-generics

I am currently using this to check if something is a class.

```js
type Class = { new (...args: any[]): any };
```

How to make it so that it only accepts classes that require a specific type of generic. For example, if I have these classes.

```js
class A<T>{}
class B<T extends any[]>{}
class C{}
```

I need a type that only accepts class B.

Answer (score 2):

You can not identify A/B/C in your example. You must have constructor in the class, and the generic must clearly

```
type Class = { new<T extends string[]>(data: T): any }

class A<T extends string> {
    data: T
    constructor(data: T) {
        this.data = data
    }
}

class B<T extends string[]> {
    data: T
    constructor(data: T) {
        this.data = data
    }
}

class C {
    data: number
    constructor(data: number) {
        this.data = data
    }
}

function test(x: Class) {
    ...
}

test(A) // Error
test(B) // OK
test(C) // Error
```

Comment: So, I guess it is imposibble to get this type without having the implementation in the constructor. I wanted to use this without knowing the class implementation (Only knowing that its generic type extends my desired type).